# composer cross package autoloading php

Tags: php, autoload, composer-php

Using composer autoloader how does one autoload between packages?

For example: How to autoload monolog classes from within myPackage?

```
/someapp
/someapp/index.php
/someapp/vendor
/someapp/vendor/myPackage
/someapp/vendor/monolog
```

I could see exponential explosion of /vendor directories if my package has a /vendor and an package using my package has a /vendor and a package using that package that uses my package has one....etc.

So how do we autoload third part dependancies cross package?

Answer (score 0):

You simply define in your package's `composer.json` that your package `require`s another package, and that be it. When `someapp` is installing composer dependencies, the dependencies of dependencies (of dependencies etc. etc. recursively ad absurdum) will all be installed in `someapp/vendor`. In `someapp/index.php` you're then including the autoload file, which allows anyone to autoload classes from any installed package.

I.e.:

*mypackage/composer.json*

```
"require": {
    "monolog": "*"
}
```

*someapp/composer.json*

```
"require": {
    "mypackage": "*"
}
```

Install:

```
$ composer install
```

Result:

```
$ ls someapp/vendor
mypackage     monolog
```